# How to serialize JSON data in to XML in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api

I have a JSON like below:

```
{
"method": "abc",
"version": "1.0.1",
"login": "123456",
"password": "abc123",
"referenceNumber": "1258",
"amount": 1.00,
"routingNumber": "145879",
"accountNumber": "145879",
"name": "abc as",
"authorizationID": "14789",
"savings": true,
"address1": "noida",
"city": "delhi",
"state": "ab",
"zip": "578945",
"phone": "1234567890",
"email": "abc@test.com",
"test": true}
```

I want it to convert it into XML, for that I wrote the following code, here MLPayment is the JSON:

```
    XmlSerializer xsSubmit = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MLPayment));
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                ns.Add("", "");
                String Body = null;
                //XmlDocument dox = new XmlDocument();
                using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
                {        
                    xsSubmit.Serialize(stringWriter, mLPayment, ns);
                    Body = stringWriter.ToString();
                }
```

1. First issue, I am getting the entire xml in double qoutes, means in string form
2. Second issue , in body I was getting `\n\r` , response is as below

`"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<ACH>\r\n  <Method>Debit</Method>\r\n  <Version>1</Version>\r\n  <Login>9</Login>\r\n  <Password>uadwaadwadwu</Password>\r\n  <ReferenceNumber>123456</ReferenceNumber>\r\n  <Amount>1.00</Amount>\r\n  <RoutingNumber>12</RoutingNumber>\r\n  <AccountNumber>123456</AccountNumber>\r\n  <Name>Joe Blow </Name>\r\n  <AuthorizationID>123456</AuthorizationID>\r\n  <Savings>true</Savings>\r\n  <Address1>SUITE 230adw</Address1>\r\n  <City>abc</City>\r\n  <State>AZ</State>\r\n  <Zip>8504445</Zip>\r\n  <Phone>1234567890</Phone>\r\n  <Email>test@abc.com</Email>\r\n  <Test>true</Test>\r\n</ACH>"`

to fix second issue, I replaced the `\n\r`

```
String cleanedReturnedValue = Body.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
String cR = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(cleanedReturnedValue);
```

after that output is:

`"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><ACH>  <Method>Debit</Method>  <Version>1</Version>  <Login>9</Login>  <Password>uadwaadwadwu</Password>  <ReferenceNumber>123456</ReferenceNumber>  <Amount>1.00</Amount>  <RoutingNumber>12</RoutingNumber>  <AccountNumber>123456</AccountNumber>  <Name>Joe Blow </Name>  <AuthorizationID>123456</AuthorizationID>  <Savings>true</Savings>  <Address1>SUITE 230adw</Address1>  <City>abc</City>  <State>AZ</State>  <Zip>8504445</Zip>  <Phone>1234567890</Phone>  <Email>test@abc.com</Email>  <Test>true</Test></ACH>"`

but the **1st** problem still remains,

1. how to I get the exact xml data instead of string
2. How do I remove slashes from `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Just use LINQ to XML, and load your string into XDocument.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><ACH>  <Method>Debit</Method>  <Version>1</Version>  <Login>9</Login>  <Password>uadwaadwadwu</Password>  <ReferenceNumber>123456</ReferenceNumber>  <Amount>1.00</Amount>  <RoutingNumber>12</RoutingNumber>  <AccountNumber>123456</AccountNumber>  <Name>Joe Blow </Name>  <AuthorizationID>123456</AuthorizationID>  <Savings>true</Savings>  <Address1>SUITE 230adw</Address1>  <City>abc</City>  <State>AZ</State>  <Zip>8504445</Zip>  <Phone>1234567890</Phone>  <Email>test@abc.com</Email>  <Test>true</Test></ACH>");
}
```

Comment: Hello @Yitzhak Khabinsky, It removes the XML version and encoding and ass curly braces at the start and end.

Comment: Response: {<ACH>
  <Method>Debit</Method>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Login>9</Login>
  <Password>uadwaadwadwu</Password>
  <ReferenceNumber>123456</ReferenceNumber>
  <Amount>1.00</Amount>
  <RoutingNumber>12</RoutingNumber>
  <AccountNumber>123456</AccountNumber>
  <Name>Joe Blow </Name>
  <AuthorizationID>123456</AuthorizationID>
  <Savings>true</Savings>
  <Address1>SUITE 230adw</Address1>
  <City>abc</City>
  <State>AZ</State>
  <Zip>8504445</Zip>
  <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
  <Email>test@abc.com</Email>
  <Test>true</Test>
</ACH>}

Comment: @skr, (1) "...It removes the XML version and encoding...". It is called XML prolog declaration. The  `XDocument` data type doesn't remove XML prolog. You just don't see it. Check `xdoc.Declaration` property. (2) "... curly braces...". Just try `xdoc.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft.json package to serialize json to xml or vice versa. The following method will convert Json to XML.

```
XNode node = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(json, "Root");
```

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-convert-json-into-xml-or-xml-into-json

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertJsonToXml.htm